# What is the correct way to rebrand an iPhone app within a single xCode project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios4

I've been asked to write scope the effort for rebranding a significant iPhone/iPad application for multiple customers, locale, languages, etc. Each incarnation of the rebrand might include different look and feel, possibly different behavior, or subsets of functionality.

My initial impression is it should be possible to use a single xCode project, and just include multiple .plist files targeted to specific project configurations. I'm unsure exactly how to accomplish this in xCode, thus I'm not sure how to accurately estimate the effort required.

I'm looking for pointers and developer references to find the most reasonable method to rebrand an existing app multiple times without forking new xCode project each time.

Comment: Do you mean different binaries that shares the same Xcode project?

Comment: @Espresso, yes exactly. One could be targeted to the French language (with appropriate French icons), another could be US-English/Canadian-English, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature I've been looking for is called "Targets" in xCode.
I'm going to use these [as described here](http://finbarrbrady.com/2010/03/building-for-multiple-targets-in-xcode/) to deploy my single project into multiple binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's possible but with [MVC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW1), Cocoa makes it easy to [localize apps](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've used a client-server approach, where everything specific to one customer is downloaded or configured from a remote server. You still need customers with overlapping requirements, but you can switch on/off modules based on the needs of a particular customer.

Low-tech approach: grab the data, configuration files, and images from a different location in the file system. Or the same location, but drop the new customer data into the directory and archive the old. A plist, a text file, a series of #defines, etc, can switch a behavior on or off. Write your code so that it doesn't know how many images, which modules, what color the buttons are, etc, until it checks the configuration and gets the data and images it needs from your directory.

Comment: By the way, I'm mostly writing about the re-branding and changing behavior parts, since I assume you can read up on localization based on language and time zone from the documentation on that topic.